# Conditional Multiplication in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to conditional multiply based on values in two columns.

The data looks like this:

If Position Long is not nan, then I want to multiply by forwarding strike price, else multiply by Position Short by forwarding strike price.

How do I do that?

Comment: In `Position Short` and `Position Long ` are empty strings? Or NaNs?

Comment: in python, it is NaN. when i copied it is blank

Comment: If both columns are NaNs, output is not changed or it is `NaN` ?

Comment: one of the column can be nan, the other will have value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If missing values are `NaN`s use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s = df['Position Long'].combine_first(df['Position Short'])
#alternative
#s = df['Position Long'].fillna(df['Position Short'])
```

If both columns are missing and need `NaN` in output:

```
df['new'] = df['Forward Strike Price'].mul(s)
```

Or if need original value:

```
df['new'] = df['Forward Strike Price'].mul(s, fill_value=1)
```